# Replace function in list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I would like to iterate through a list of strings and replace each instance of a character ('1', for example) with a word. I am confused why this would not work.

```
for x in list_of_strings:
    x.replace('1', 'Ace')
```

Side note, the strings within the lists are multiple characters long. ('1 of Spades)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
list_of_strings = [x.replace('1', 'Ace') for x in list_of_strings]
```

This is natural in Python. There is no significant benefit in changing your original list directly; both methods will have O(*n*) time complexity.

The reason your code does not work is `str.replace` does not work in place. It returns a copy, as [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). You *can* iterate over a `range` object to modify your list:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
    list_of_strings[i] = list_of_strings[i].replace('1', 'Ace')
```

Or use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for idx, value in enumerate(list_of_strings):
    list_of_strings[idx] = value.replace('1', 'Ace')
```

Comment: In-place version would look nicer with `enumerate`, in my opinion.