# Remove ")" from cells in list if ")" exists

Tags: python, list, data-cleaning, parentheses, code-cleanup

Could you please tell me how can I remove ")" from strings in a list without converting the list to a string? Example:

Input:

```
list =[
 'ABDDDDC 1,000 IWJBCKNBCDVV',
 'BDISJBJ 2,000 DBFIAJDBDIAJ',
 'JDBISJB 5,000 AHSBIEFEWEFJ)', # there is a parenthesis at the end
 'CONDDDD 7,000 4DJVBDISJEVV)'] # there is a parenthesis at the end
```

Expected output:

```
list =[
 'ABDDDDC 1,000 IWJBCKNBCDVV',
 'BDISJBJ 2,000 DBFIAJDBDIAJ',
 'JDBISJB 5,000 AHSBIEFEWEFJ', # parenthesis is removed
 'CONDDDD 7,000 4DJVBDISJEVV'] # parenthesis is removed
```

I know how to do it by converting list to str like following:

```
a = str(list)
a = a.replace(")","")
print(a)
```

However, since I need convert it to a dataframe later... I want to keep it as list.
Please let me know if you need any clarificaiton for my question. This is my first time to post a question.

Comment: `[item.replace(')', '') for item in list]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace function in list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285502/replace-function-in-list-of-strings)

Comment: OP upı should accept one of the answers. You asked for help. They helped...

Comment: `[item.rstrip(")") for item in list]` if you only want to eliminate the `")"` at the end. And don't use `list` as variable name, you're overriding a builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a list comprehension here:

```py
inp = ['ABDDDDC 1,000 IWJBCKNBCDVV', 'BDISJBJ 2,000 DBFIAJDBDIAJ', 'JDBISJB 5,000 AHSBIEFEWEFJ)', 'CONDDDD 7,000 4DJVBDISJEVV)']
output = [re.sub(r'\)$', '', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['ABDDDDC 1,000 IWJBCKNBCDVV',
 'BDISJBJ 2,000 DBFIAJDBDIAJ',
 'JDBISJB 5,000 AHSBIEFEWEFJ',
 'CONDDDD 7,000 4DJVBDISJEVV']
```

Comment: `str.replace` is just as good as regex for a substitution this simple.

Comment: Yes, that might be fine, but perhaps the OP really only wants to target `)` at the very end of each string.

Comment: That's not clear.  The comment "# there is a parenthesis at the end" sort of implies it, but we don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your solution but ")" is still there... maybe it's because I used re.findall() to get the value of the list from a HTML file....

Comment: Well my answer doesn't use `re.findall` and you are not using my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for that.

```
list =[
 'ABDDDDC 1,000 IWJBCKNBCDVV',
 'BDISJBJ 2,000 DBFIAJDBDIAJ',
 'JDBISJB 5,000 AHSBIEFEWEFJ)',
 'CONDDDD 7,000 4DJVBDISJEVV)']

list = [i.replace(')','') if ')' in i else i for i in list]
[print(x) for x in list]
```

Comment: You don't need the `if`-`else`.